# Mac OS: Smart Folders and Subfolders

Tags: macos, directory, subdirectory

Mac OS has the built-in smart folder feature that can narrow down files in a specific location based on a given set of properties (e.g. file extension, size, creation date, etc.).

I am trying to declutter my desktop by file type, and want to select all images on my desktop to place in a separate folder. The thing is, the smart folder seems to select all image files that are nested within the desktop's subfolders. Is there anyway to select files excluding the ones located in subfolders?

Thanks!
~ Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Open a standard Finder window and navigate to your Desktop folder. Set the window to list view and sort by clicking on the Kind column header. Now all your images will be grouped together by image type. Select each group by clicking on the first file in the group and shift clicking on the last, then drag into your destination folder.

HTH